# Unable to send data to iframe from parent window using postMessage in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain, postmessage

I'm developing a Google Chrome Extension that injects a script on a webpage, gather some data from the web page, call an iframe and send that data to the iframe. Since this process needs to be cross-domain, postMessage was the only thing i could think of for implementing this however i'm not able to receive this data in iframe.
**(Btw, is there any other method by which i can achieve same functionality?)**
Below is my script that i inject on a webpage when a user clicks on the extension.

```
jQuery('body').append('<div style="height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; position: fixed !important; margin: 0% auto !important; background: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.9) !important; left: 0 !important; right: 0 !important; z-index: 99999999 !important; top: 0% !important;" id="image-grabber-container"><iframe id="vwframe" src="https://example.com/abcd.php"  frameborder="0" style="display: block !important; position: fixed !important; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; bottom: 0px !important; right: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; clip: auto !important; z-index: 7147483657 !important;"></iframe></div>');

setTimeout(function(){
    var dTitle = document.title;
    var receiver = document.getElementById('vwframe').contentWindow;
    receiver.postMessage(dTitle, '*');
},1000);
```

I've used `setTimeout` here just to make sure that iframe is available/loaded when i post message.
Now, i call a script in the iframe to receive the message:

```
window.onload = function() {
        function receiveMessage1(e) {
            console.log('mSG');
            if (e.origin !== currentUrl)
                return;

            parentTitle = e.data;
            console.log(parentTitle);
        }
        if (window.addEventListener){
            console.log('if');
          window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage1, false);
          console.log('if end');
        } else {
            console.log('else');
          attachEvent("onmessage", receiveMessage1);
          console.log('else end');
        }
}
```

I see no error in console however `receiveMessage1` function fails to work. What could be the possible reason for this?


**P.S. I was able to send message from iframe to parent but not vice versa.**

Comment: You should not use setTimeout inside iframe otherwise you'll add message event after the message.

Comment: @jcubic I wasn't using setTimeout initially but that didn't worked either. Was just experimenting..

Comment: To clarify: your iframe does print `if`, `if end`, but not `mSG`?

Comment: Also, yes. You're waiting to attach a listener, which doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: @Xan Exactly.. it does print IF, IF END but not mSG

Comment: I just removed the setTimeout for attaching the listener in iframe but still...no success...

Comment: Update the code in the question, please.

Comment: @charlietfl This is the value of receiver - Window {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 0, frames: Window…}

Comment: Try also not using window.onload.

Comment: @jcubic then what should i use? What should be the approach to get this thing done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not using setTimeout and window.onload, just this instead:

```
<script>

    function receiveMessage1(e) {
        console.log('mSG');
        if (e.origin !== currentUrl)
            return;

        parentTitle = e.data;
        console.log(parentTitle);
    }
    if (window.addEventListener){
        console.log('if');
      window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage1, false);
      console.log('if end');
    } else {
        console.log('else');
      attachEvent("onmessage", receiveMessage1);
      console.log('else end');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still is not showing me `console.log('mSG')`. Any possible error that i might be doing in this?

Comment: Finally i got a glimpse of this working but, it is not working always. Sounds quite stupid to me but what exactly is happening that it works barely 2 out of 10 times. And what i mean from 'WORKING' is it shows 'mSG' in console.

Comment: @TusharShukla Maybe use `$('iframe').load(function() {` instead of `setTimeout`.

Comment: A 1000 upvotes for you (only if i could :p).. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, using `postMessage()` method is still the more secure way of passing messages across domains.

To use this method, please note that it accepts two parameters:

- `message` – A string or object that will be sent to the receiving
  window.
- `targetOrigin` – The URL of the window that the message is being sent
  to. The protocol, port and hostname of the target window must match
  this parameter for the message to be sent. Specifying "*" will match
  any URL however this is strongly discouraged for security reasons.

And, this method should be called on the window that the message is being set to. A reference to the target window can be obtained in a number of different ways:

- When using `window.open()` a reference to the new window will be
  returned by the `open()` method.
- For iframes you can access the `contentWindow` property on the desired
  iframe.

  > `targetWindow.postMessage('Hello World!', 'http://example.com');`

Usage tips, more information regarding the implementation and complete guide are given in this blog - [Cross-Domain Messaging With postMessage](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage) and I think this SO post - [Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page?rq=1) will be helpful too.